# Why I should not perform a Restore-SPSite for a copy of a site collection on the same content database?

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, restore, content-database

I have read these links which talks about using `Backup-SPsite` && `Restore-SPSite`:-

- [link1](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2014/03/10/sharepoint-stsadm-backuprestore-vs-importexport-3/)
- [link2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/aaf5af16-8fe2-4b84-8e31-9f759b3b6d74/import-vs-backup-for-site-collection)

and they both mentioned that restoring a copy of a site collection's back-up file file using `Restore-SPSite` will mainly create a new GUID for the site but will reserve the GUID for the site collection's components such as its subsite, content type, etc... so they mentioned that we should do the `Restore-SPSite` on a new Content Database to avoid GUID conflict..

so I did the following test:-

- I have the following site collection "`http://..../businessfunctions`".
- I backup it.
- then I restore a new site collection (`http://..../testsite`) using the backup file inside the same content database (Actually I only have one content database).
- and I did not get any exception,, or any error message about any GUID conflict..

so now I have 2 site collections (`/businessfunction` & `/testsite`), that have the same GUIDs for their; subsites, content types, etc... but I am able to work on these 2 site collections without having any problem.

So can anyone adivce why all the links which talk about `Restore-SPSite` mentioned that we need to restore on a different content database to avoid duplicate or conflict in GUIDs ??? In other words where I will face problems if I have for example 2 subsites that have the same GUIDs ,and their site collections are inside the same content database?? 
Here is a screenshot of the scripts which I perform:-

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just look at the code snippet below and try to imagine the scenario of what will happen:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://somesite")) {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SameGuid)) {
        return web.Url;
    }
}
```

The above code can raise an exception because two web objects would be returned, there are infinite scenarios where GUID is used to fetch an instance and every time there would be 2 cases:

1. It will take the first one (Worst case)
2. Throw an Exception (Developer will scratch his head!)

To maintain data integrity, avoid future hassle regarding scalability and enhancement, it is advised to restore Sp-Site under new Content DB.

GUID for a site collection is unique and it gets stored along with the site collection backup.
Your content database has a table called dbo.sites with a column named "id"

[image]

**At the end I would just say that even if you are able to Restore-SpSite with some workaround, it would be a big design flaw and would create problems in the future as this [blog](http://sharepointinterface.com/2011/04/03/finding-duplicate-guids-in-your-sharepoint-site-collection/) states.**

Comment: but even if i restore on new content DB ,, i think all the site collections's content such as subsites, lists, etc will still have the same gUID as their source site collection is this correct ?? also in your code snippet still two web objects will be returned even if they are inside seperate content DB..,, or if i restore on new content db all the site collection's content will get new GUID compared to their source ?

Comment: Your content database has a table called dbo.sites with a column named "id". I would really suggest you to read this article http://sharepointinterface.com/2011/04/03/finding-duplicate-guids-in-your-sharepoint-site-collection/

Comment: but using Restore-SPSite will create new GUID for the site even on the same content database,, so the id will not be duplicated

Comment: Backup-SPsite is an exact mirror and would retain GUID's.

Comment: creating a different content db would be a workaround to get the site restored but it would not be a good solution. You can look into Export-Import of site

Comment: Yes but when you use Restore-spsote it will use the same GUID as the source site collection except for the site collection GUID ,, it will generate new site collection GUID but all the other contents, such as subsite, lists, stc will have the same GUID...you can check my original question i showed how new GUID was generated for the site collection when i use restore-spssite..

Comment: I did not get your point now if i do a Restore-SPSite on the same content database, the restore site collection will get a new GUID even on the same content database, but all the site collection's contents such as subsites, lists, will get the same GUID as the source site collection,, so is this a problem ? i still can not understand why i need to restore on a new database ? as if i use new content database or i used existing content database to restore a site collection i will get new GUID for the site collection and the same GUID for its contents...

Comment: I tried to replicate and got guid conflict error, there can be 2 cases here.1. I didn't use -Force and you used it. 2. You created a site collection first and restored on the top of it.
In both the cases even if you were able to restore the site, my initial answer stands where you'll face problems in future. Getting an object with GUID would throw error. Do look into the link I gave earlier, it's a design mistake and must be avoided.

Comment: MS didn't allow us to manually give guid to a component and there's a reason behind it :)

Comment: i ended up creating these subsites from scratch without any backup or restore,, i did this to avoid any GUID conflicts,, altohugh on MSDN they mentioned i can restore on the same farm and also on the same content DB ,, but still having duplicate guid is something that i will keep worrying about, so i did not take this risk !!

Comment: A site template restore would have been good, but yea you took the better approach of not having same guid.